# pandas function to find sum of columns for different index level in multi level index table

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pivot, multi-index

How to find sum of values for different index level in multi level index table, and represent it in the indexes as a summation row

For example

```
Gender Age Marks
M.      20. 30
            45
        22. 46
            33
F.      20. 44
            46
        22. 42
            31
```

In this data frame how to find sum of F&20..and represent it as a row below age 20 marks
 As :sum 90

Comment: Do you mean to group by gender and Age?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I have understand you correctly, but it seems that you want to group by `Gender` and `Age`:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Gender": ['M.','M.','M.','M.','F.','F.','F.','F.'],
    "Age":[20.,20.,22.,22.,20,20,22,22],
    'Marks':[30,45,46,33,44,46,42,31] })
df.groupby(['Gender','Age'])['Marks'].sum()
```

Result:

```
Gender  Age 
F.      20.0    90
        22.0    73
M.      20.0    75
        22.0    79
```